# MOTIF GUI programming

Tags: gcc, motif

MOTIF GUI PROGRAMMING !
Hi there. I am a MOTIF GUI Programmer in C language.
After a longer break i have problems with the GCC compiling.
my MOTIF file is named winstack.c

The compilation runs good.
But no executable LINUX FILE is created. except a file named newprogram.
The properties of the file in the context menue is "shared library" not "executable".
Thats my problem.
From commandline is no problem with ./newprogram. A GUI Windows is opening.
How about a real linux exe to start with one click in file explorer ???
Kindly Regards
SM

i followed the description of GCC Manual.

gcc -o newprogram  winstack.c  -lXm -lXt -lX11

I expected a linux executable file to start from file explorer with a mouseclick.

Comment: You explicitly tell `gcc` to build a program named `newprogram`, which will be written to the current directory. You should be able to run it with e.g. `./newprogram`.

Comment: yeah from command line. But normally the file is a real executable to start with one mouseklick from file explorer. And in the "right mouse" context menue you can see the attribute "EXECUTABLE"  not "shared library".  How about that ?

Comment: Is your windowing system configured to start with single clicks? And of course it's an executable program, otherwise you would not be able to run it, and that's also what you tell `gcc` to create. I think you need to take a couple of steps back and refresh your Unix/Linux knowledge.

Comment: hi , yes i can start with single clicks. i have a linux executable of the same program from 5 months ago. a real executable.  [ the driving wheel look like file]

Comment: Hi , i have solved the problem.  I have installed the CLANG compiler. That makes executables as expected. GCC not , and i have posted a question to the LINUX OS Distrubutor WHY? He can have the answer.

Comment: If you solved it in a way that you think could benefit others in the future, then please write an *answer* explaining what you did and how you solved it.